# CSS Transition not working on my website but works on codepen

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

I have a simple CSS transition for when you hover over a button it eases into the box-shadow. But for some reason, the transition doesn't work on my site. I have other CSS transitions on my site that work just fine but this one is being difficult. Is there anything that could potentially block a transition? The `:hover` is instant opposed to using an eased in effect like I was aiming for.

I'm using Sass but I am not sure if that makes a difference:

```
.btn.btn-more {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-width: 130px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;

    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #999;
    }
}
```

This site is using Bootstrap 2.3.2 which is where that `.btn` comes from. I have tried this in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Are you processing the sass/scss file into css before you upload it to your site?

Comment: @dwjohnston This is in a local environment where it automatically processes the SCSS. All changes I make to the button's CSS takes effect except the transition.

Comment: Could you try do a nested selector - just to check that the sass is infact processing correctly? eg. `div { &.foo {color: red;}}`

Comment: @dwjohnston I just discovered the issue. `.btn` was overriding the transitions. Not sure why or how but it wasn't showing in chrome until I opened the page in a new tab. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`.btn` is overriding the transitions and Chrome dev tools wasn't showing that override until I opened the page in a new tab and opened dev tools again.